# Which property changes punctuation color/foreground in monaco editor defineTheme?

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

hope this is a silly question and easy to solve.
I'm trying to make a custom code editor with monaco editor in react, so I'm using the @monaco-editor/react library. To customize it I went with the defineTheme function provided by the base monaco editor library, and this is what I got:

```
monaco.editor.defineTheme('my-theme', {
  base: 'vs',
  inherit: true,
  rules: [],
  colors: {
    foreground: '#cccce5',
    'editor.foreground': '#cccce5',
    'textSeparator.foreground': '#cccce5',
    'editor.background': '#00004c',
    'editorCursor.foreground': '#00000050',
    'editor.lineHighlightBackground': '#00000050',
    'editorLineNumber.foreground': '#008800',
    'editor.selectionBackground': '#00000050',
    'editor.inactiveSelectionBackground': '#00000050',
    'editorWidget.background': '#00000050',
    'editorWidget.foreground': '#cccce5',
  },
})
```

It's looking pretty good until now, but the one problem I have is I have white text when writing code, but all the punctuation and symbols are black, and I can't find which property changes this color. I'm mainly using this tool from microsoft to learn how I'm supposed to customize it: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#customizing-the-appearence-exposed-colors

You can get in that website, replace the default code with mine, then below that change language from 'text-plain' to 'javascript', then click run and you'll see the issue I'm having

Answer (score 0):

The color values you specified in the `colors` object are used for other elements, but not syntax highlighting. Instead specify your syntax colors in the `rule` array. Another example, specifically made to [demo syntax colors](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#customizing-the-appearence-tokens-and-colors) allows you to experiment with that.

For example, add `{ token: "delimiter.html", foreground: "#00FF00"}` to the `rule` array to color delimiter tokens in green:

[image]

Read the comment in that text which hints you at a very useful little tool (shown in the image) that let's you inspect the tokens that were assigned by the current tokenizer (here the built-in HTML tokenizer).